# How to concat rotated logs back together

Tags: logging, logrotate, cat

How to concatenate the rotated logs back together to make the original file?

```
huali-access.log     huali-access.log.15  huali-access.log.21  huali-access.log.28  huali-access.log.34  huali-access.log.40  huali-access.log.47  huali-access.log.6
huali-access.log.1   huali-access.log.16  huali-access.log.22  huali-access.log.29  huali-access.log.35  huali-access.log.41  huali-access.log.48  huali-access.log.7
huali-access.log.10  huali-access.log.17  huali-access.log.23  huali-access.log.3   huali-access.log.36  huali-access.log.42  huali-access.log.49  huali-access.log.8
huali-access.log.11  huali-access.log.18  huali-access.log.24  huali-access.log.30  huali-access.log.37  huali-access.log.43  huali-access.log.5   huali-access.log.9
huali-access.log.12  huali-access.log.19  huali-access.log.25  huali-access.log.31  huali-access.log.38  huali-access.log.44  huali-access.log.50
huali-access.log.13  huali-access.log.2   huali-access.log.26  huali-access.log.32  huali-access.log.39  huali-access.log.45  huali-access.log.51
huali-access.log.14  huali-access.log.20  huali-access.log.27  huali-access.log.33  huali-access.log.4   huali-access.log.46  huali-access.log.52
```

Comment: What is your final purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this:

```
cat huali-access.log* > merged-huali-access.log
```

or to be sure its chronologically in order:

```
echo -n "" > merged-huali-access.log # creating new file and making sure its empty
for i in {1..52}
do
    cat huali-access.log.${i} >> merged-huali-access.log
done
cat huali-access.log >> merged-huali-access.log
```

Comment: Why do you have the 'echo -n ""' bit there?  That is superfluous.  The concatenation ">>" operation will create an empty file just as done by ">".

Comment: @Daniel If the file is already there, it won't empty the file.

Comment: @ianweller ... ack ... too true.

Answer (score 9):

If the files have the correct modification times set (e.g. you did not copy them around without taking care of preserving the modification times), you can use

```
 cat $(ls -t huali-access.log*) > output.log
```

The `-t` option in ls will sort it by modification time.

Comment: cat $(ls -t -r huali-access.log*) > output.log to reverse the file order. Oldest file first so that the chronological order is maintained on the output.log.

Answer (score 0):

From @mauro.stettler, Fixed issue with order of files, also made it generic:

```
for LOG in *.log; do 
    ( for i in {100..1}; do 
       F=${LOG}.${i}; 
       [ -e $F ] && cat $F; 
    done ; cat ${LOG} ) > aggregated_${LOG};
done
```

Or you can use on accesslogs, not so generic as the other that you can apply to any logs, and will not work with among different months:

```
cat accesslog.log* | sort -nk 4 > aggregated_accesslog.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This will concatenate all log* files (including gzipped) into log.all
Just replace "log" to use it

```
l='log'; test -f ${l}.all && rm ${l}.all; ls -1tr ${l}* | xargs zcat -f >> $l.all
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -1t *.access.log* | xargs zcat >  access.all.log
```